# Can't download Umbraco CMS with NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, umbraco, nuget

Whenever I try to NuGet the "Umbraco CMS" package I get the following message:

```
Install-Package : Part URI is not valid per rules defined in the Open Packaging Conventions specification.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  umbracocms
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Any ideas? I can NuGet other packages without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you experienced with the UmbracoCms nuget was caused by package being corrupted by the nuget package tool. Tom Fulton sent me this screenshot (http://cl.ly/image/100d25270J3F), which shows the content of the version 6.1.2.1 package looking fairly strange.

I have repackaged the UmbracoCms and UmbracoCms.Core packages today, so they should be working again. Have tested and verified that it works locally using "Install-Package UmbracoCms" and using package restore.

Answer (score 0):

Is the space in "Umbraco CMS" the issue?  I can nuget it from VS as follows:

- Tools | Library Package Manager | Package Manager Console
- PM> install-package umbracocms (hit enter key)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To clarify I'm using the GUI - I'll have another go with the GUI and try the console now and report back.

Comment: Right, neither the GUI nor the console method worked but I do have more error message so I'll update my question with that.